# how do I get the input to read as a 0 even if there is no user input

Tags: java, try-catch

I have this code for a school assignment that I failed because it did not run to my professors standards. I could not figure out how to get the program to run even if there was only input in one of the two boxes. If one box is left blank it goes to the catch and displays the error message "Please Enter A Valid Number". I was maybe thinking creating an arrayList for the user inputs and adding that together?

This is the snippet of code for the boxes:

```java
    JButton creditButton = new JButton("CREDIT");
        creditButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                double num1=0, num2=0, balance=0;
                
                try {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(creditInput.getText());
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(debitInput.getText());
                    balance = num1 - num2;
                    
                    totalBalance.setText("$" + Double.toString(balance));
                }catch(Exception e2) {
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter A Valid Number");
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        JButton debitButton = new JButton("DEBIT");
        debitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
double num1=6, num2=6, balance=0;
                
                try {
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(creditInput.getText());
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(debitInput.getText());
                    balance = num1 - num2;
                    
                    totalBalance.setText("$" + Double.toString(balance));
                }catch(Exception e2) {
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter A Valid Number");
                }
            }
        });
        
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("CLEAR");
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                creditInput.setText("");
                debitInput.setText("");
                }
        });
```

Comment: As written the exception handling is too broad because it covers both inputs at once. Isolate each input. If there's a parsing exception you need to know *why* there's an exception, which can only be done by looking at the input and seeing if the *string representation* is a valid number, e.g., an empty string could be `0` if you want, but `abc` should still be an error.

Comment: (I'd think an empty input would be an error, but that's neither here nor there.)

Comment: @DaveNewton ok. So I do apologize as I am very new to this but I think what you are saying is I need to know that there is an exception because if someone tries to enter something other than a valid number an error needs to pop up. The catch all : 
```catch(Exception e2)``` is not good enough because it will not run if there is nothing there. So I tried ```ArithmeticException e ``` as well but that gave me actual errors in the coding.

Answer (score 1):

Check if input is null and if it is set it to 0

```
    if(creditInput.getText() == null){
        num1 = 0.0;
    }else{
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(creditInput.getText());
    }
    if(debitInput.getText() == null){
        num2 = 0.0;
    }else{
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(debitInput.getText());
    }
    balance = num1 - num2;
```